# Labeling issue after converting database

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, labeling, arcgis-10.4

I am using ArcMap 10.4.1 and I converted from a .mdb to a file geodatabase. Now the label class has stopped working. The following example is what it used to be, but now I am not able to get it to verify. I have tried to remove the brackets from Label_Class and PIN, but that didn't work. Any suggestions on how to correct?

[Label_Class] = 572 AND NOT (mid( [PIN],5,1) = '6')

[image]

Comment: Syntax changes during migration. Check the following: 
http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/geodatabases/migrating-to-the-file-geodatabase.htm

WHERE clause syntax for a personal geodatabase:

[STATE_NAME] = 'California'

Equivalent syntax for a file geodatabase

"STATE_NAME" = 'California'

Answer (score 2):

If you check the [**SQL reference for query expressions used in ArcGIS**](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.4/map/working-with-layers/sql-reference-for-query-expressions-used-in-arcgis.htm), you'll see that fields are referenced differently in personal geodatabases vs file geodatabases.

> To specify a field in an SQL expression, provide a delimiter if the
>   field name would otherwise be ambiguous, such as if it were the same
>   as an SQL reserved keyword.
>
> Since there are many reserved keywords, and new ones can be added in
>   subsequent releases, a good practice is to always enclose a field name
>   with a delimiter.
>
> Field name delimiters differ from DBMS to DBMS. If you're querying any
>   file-based data, such as a file geodatabase, ArcSDE geodatabase data,
>   or data in an ArcIMS feature class or image service sublayer, you can
>   enclose field names in double quotes:
>
> "AREA"
>
> If you're querying personal geodatabase data, you can enclose
>   fields in square brackets:
>
> [AREA]
>
> For personal geodatabase raster datasets, you should enclose
>   field names in double quotes:
>
> "AREA"
>
> For File geodatabase data you can enclose your field names in
>   double quotes, but it's generally not needed.
>
> AREA

So, your label expression should read:

```
Label_Class = 572 AND NOT (mid( PIN,5,1) = '6')
```

or, if you enclose the fields in double quotes:

```
"Label_Class" = 572 AND NOT (mid( "PIN",5,1) = '6')
```